# What are the limtations of Keys in PHP can they be objects them selves?

Tags: php, arrays

I was trying to displaying a menu that I have broken down into categories and items. There is ManyToOne relationship between the item and the category. Can I store the array to have object as keys. Here is my example.

```
['category1'] => array 
           (
             itemObj_1
             itemObj_2
             itemObj_3
           )
['category2'] => array 
           (
             itemObj_1
             itemObj_2
             itemObj_3
           )
['category3'] => array 
           (
             itemObj_1
             itemObj_2
             itemObj_3
```

Category strings would be objects that hold information about the array of objects they are associated with. I could not find any documentation on this. Can you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they can only be of type `scalar`, the values can be anything.

Check this out: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Basically any scalar type can be used, but it will eventually get typecast down to either a `string` or an `integer`. The docs explicitly says you cannot use arrays or objects as keys.